# I want to multiply two defined functionals in class, but I got this error . what I must do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class well_2D:

    def __init__(self,d):
        self.d=d

    def φ_x(self,l,x):
        if l%2==0 :
            return np.sqrt(2/self.d)*np.sin(np.pi*l*x/self.d)
        else :
            return np.sqrt(2/self.d)*np.cos(np.pi*l*x/self.d)

    def φ_y(self,m,y):
        if l%2==0 :
            return np.sqrt(2/self.d)*np.sin(np.pi*m*y/self.d)
        else :
            return np.sqrt(2/self.d)*np.cos(np.pi*m*y/self.d)

    def Ψ(self,l,m,x,y):
        return φ_x*φ_y
```

Usage:

```
Q=well_2D(2)

Q.Ψ(2,1,2,2)

>>>TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'function'
```

Comment: Did you mean to call the functions?  `return φ_x(l, x) * φ_y(m, y)`

Comment: Both functions are identical; the only difference is the arguments passed when you call them. (Ignoring the apparent typo in using `l` in the definition of `φ_y`.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the function signatures, you meant to write this:

```
return self.φ_x(l, x) * self.φ_y(m, y)
```

BTW `l` is a bad variable name since it looks like `1` and `I`. You could use `L` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For various reasons, you cannot multiply functions themselves, only the results of calling them. In this case, I would refactor your code significantly:

```
class Well2D:

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d

    def φ(self, l, x):
        f = np.sin if l % 2 == 0 else np.cos
        return np.sqrt(2/self.d) * f(np.pi * l * x / self.d)

    def Ψ(self, l, m, x, y):
        return self.φ(l, x) * self.φ(m, y)
```

Inside `φ`, the only difference between the two cases is the trigonometric function you call based on the parity of `l`. There is no difference between `φ_x` and `φ_y`, other than the arguments you pass to each call, so just define a single function `φ`.